# php not running on browser

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I'm a novice, I installed php5 and apache2 on ubuntu,

I wrote this basic php script

```
<?
   phpinfo();
?>
```

But, when I open the file in the browser, it only "downloads" the file, it doesn't run the script and show me the necessary info.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have Apache configured correctly for PHP, and so it is simply returning the PHP file like it would anything it doesn't recognize.

Comment: I ran even into worse situation.... I just forgot to install php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you are missing something. Try this manual: http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/28/how-to-install-lamp-apache-mysql-php-on-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: This was a great start but the PHP inside my HTML files isn't executing unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You have one of two problems:

- (More likely) Your php.ini file has [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) disabled, and will not interpret the short form of the PHP open tag `<?`, and you need to use the full `<?php` open tag.
- Your Apache installation is not configured to use PHP to process `.php` files. You need to, at a minimum, ensure this line is present `httpd.conf`:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

There will also probably be other configuration needed in Apache, depending on how you are running PHP - the link provided by Sergei Tulentsev should help you determine if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

you can't open a php file like a html one (i.e. double clicking) it must be in your `DocumentRoot` and you go there in your browser usually localhost/mypage.php. Check apache's httpd.conf file for where it has the document root set move your file there and go to the afformentioned address.

Answer (score 0):

If you could not solve your problem using your given solutions here, you can install Apache and MySQL using something like [Xampp for linux](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) more easily.